# If elements are in view

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with a block of code which works well to check to see if 1 single element is visible within the browsers window, but I want to be able to extend this to check to see if any of 3 separate elements are in view at the time of scrolling. Code for single which works is below:

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};


$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  if ($('.footerWrapper').isInViewport()) {
    console.log("footer in view")
  } else {
    console.log("footer out of view")
  }
});
```

How can I adapt this to say

if `.footerWrapper` || `.blueWrapper` || `.carousel` are in view....

Comment: Well, you could just call it 3 times, or make something new to take in an array then check each item in the array with your current function

Comment: OK - so, maybe set a var with a +1 value for when it matches to show the item in view - then if var > 0 one of the items is in view... good idea... will give that a go...

Comment: 1 or 0, true or false, as soon as an item is in view, you can return the value so the rest of the loop do not need to run. You could also use `filter` as Mosh's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if any of the elements in the jQuery object (what `$` returns) is in the viewport using [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```js
function inViewport(item) {
  var elementTop = item.offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + item.outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
}

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  const elements = this;
  const found = elements.filter(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    return inViewport(item);
  });
  return !!found.length;
};
```

Demo

```js
function inViewport(item) {
  var elementTop = item.offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + item.outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
}

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  const elements = this;
  const found = elements.filter(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    return inViewport(item);
  });

  return !!found.length;
};


setInterval(() => {
  console.log(
    $('.element1,.element2').isInViewport()
  );
}, 2000)
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

<div class="element1">element1</div>
<div class="element2">element2</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/yukunun/edit?html,css,js,output